# Why forecast::accuracy() mape is working with 0/0?

Tags: r, forecasting, mape

I'm learning now some metrics of goodness about time series forecasting, using the `forecast` package, but I'm stuck in something that surely I've not understood well. I have two vectors, of real data, and forecast data, and I'd like to calculate MAPE.

```
real <- c(1,2,3,0)
pred <- c(2,3,1,0) 
accuracy(pred,real)
         ME     RMSE MAE       MPE     MAPE
Test set  0 1.224745   1 -27.77778 72.22222
```

So I decided to try to calculate myself the MAPE, using the [docs](https://otexts.com/fpp2/accuracy.html), so:

```
mean(abs((real-pred)/real*100))
[1] NaN
```

And clearly I got `NaN`, because I have a `(0-0)/0`.

My question is: am I calculating wrong manually the MAPE, or the function has a kind of `na.rm = TRUE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that this should not really happen. And no, you are not doing anything wrong in calculating the MAPE.

(Note that `accuracy()` expects its first argument to be the forecast, and the second one to be the actuals.)

What seems to be happening is that `accuracy()` removes all data points where *both* forecasts and actuals are zero - but only for the MPE and the MAPE - and then calculates the KPIs for the remaining data points. The other KPIs are calculated with all data.

```
> library(forecast)
> 
> accuracy(c(1,2,3,0),c(2,3,1,0))
         ME     RMSE MAE       MPE     MAPE
Test set  0 1.224745   1 -38.88889 94.44444
> 
> accuracy(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,1))
         ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE
Test set  0 1.414214 1.333333 -38.88889 94.44444
```

If we have a non-zero forecast corresponding to a zero actual, we get the correct `Inf`:

```
> accuracy(c(1,2,3,1),c(2,3,1,0))
            ME     RMSE  MAE  MPE MAPE
Test set -0.25 1.322876 1.25 -Inf  Inf
```

I think the behavior makes a kind of sense, but it should be documented in the help page for `accuracy()`. Perhaps you want to [create a ticket and request that this be documented](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues), linking to this thread? For the record, this applies to `forecast` version 8.9 under R version 3.6.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! As soon as possible I'll create a ticket about it (I've not a github profile, but it's on my to do list), also edited the question with the right order.